# I am trying to show that $xR\cap yR$ is not finitely generated where $R=\mathbb{Z}+(x,y)\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

My ideals are the following: $xR=x\mathbb{Z}+(x^2,xy)\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and $yR=y\mathbb{Z}+(xy,x^2)\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. So $xR\cap yR=xy\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. Now it remains to see that $xy\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is not finitely generated. And I am stuck here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a finite set $S_i\in xy\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ let 
$$S_i=\frac{p_i}{q_i}xy+\cdots$$

and let $q$ be the least common multiple of the $q_i$. Then all elements of 
$(S_1,S_2\cdots)R$ have coefficients of $xy$ with denominator dividing $q$.

Comment: So $xy/q\in xy\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ but not in $(S_1,S_2,...)R$.

Comment: No, but take $p$ prime, $p\not |q$ then $\frac{1}{p}xy$ is not in $(S)R$.